# Use javascript to grab the filename of file selected in Rails form_for file_field before submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am writing code to launch a js popup that will require a user to confirm before they make a specific destructive action by overwriting data with a rails `form_for`. I already have the js popup and some other logic working, my last remaining task is that I only want this js popup to activate *if a file has been attached in a specific `file_field` on the form.* If there is no file attached on that `file_field` I don't need this to popup.

How can I grab the status of whether or not there is currently a file attached / the filename? Here is my current relevant code. The syntax is Slim:

**Form View: Relevant file_field section**

```
tr
  = f.fields_for :location_csv, LocationCSV.new do |p|
    td = p.label :attachment, "#{@campaign.form_attributes[:location_csv][:label]}"
    td.csv-example
      - if @campaign.has_entrants_with_locations?
      p.alert Warning: Updating Will Delete Location Information For Past Completed Entries
      = p.file_field :attachment, accept: "text/csv", class: 'form-control'
```

**Form View: Submit Button Section including some other logic**

```
tr
  td colspan='2'= f.submit class: "button success", id: "btn-form-submit", onclick: "destructionWarning(#{@campaign.has_entrants_with_locations?})"
```

**Javascript Snippet**

```
function destructionWarning(status) {
  if (status === true) {
    if (confirm("WARNING: This update will delete the store location data for #{@campaign.entrants_with_locations_count} campaign entrant#{'s' if @campaign.entrants_with_locations_count > 1}! Cancel to abort.") == true) {}
    else {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: Here is my updated javascript snippet:

```
var csvElement = document.getElementById("quiz_campaign_location_csv_attributes_attachment");
var csvAttachment = csvElement.value;

function destructionWarning(status) {
  if (status === true && csvAttachment != "") {
    if (confirm("WARNING: This update will delete the store location data for #{@campaign.entrants_with_locations_count} campaign entrant#{'s' if @campaign.entrants_with_locations_count > 1}! Cancel to abort.") == true) {}
    else {
    event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the HTML id of the file field input element?  You should be able to test the value of the input for an empty string.

Let's assume the id of the file input element id is `attachment`.

Using plain Javascript:

```
var file_input = document.getElementById("attachment");
var filename = file_input.value;
if( filename != "" ) {
  // There is a file specified
} else {
  // There is no file specified
}
```

Using jQuery:

```
if( $('#attachment').val() != "" ) {
  // There is a file specified
} else {
  // There is no file specified
}
```

If you want to test for the presence of the filename in your `destructionWarning` function:

```
function destructionWarning(server_status) {
  if (server_status == true) {
    var file_input = document.getElementById("attachment");
    var filename = file_input.value;
    if( filename != "" ) { // user has attached a file
      var user_confirmed = confirm("WARNING: This update will delete the store location data for #{@campaign.entrants_with_locations_count} campaign entrant#{'s' if @campaign.entrants_with_locations_count > 1}! Cancel to abort.");
      if ( user_confirmed != true) { 
        // cancel the form submission
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The element id is `quiz_campaign_location_csv_attributes_attachment`. I have all of that working. Almost everything seems to work as I need it to, if I am interpreting the behavior correctly I think the remaining piece is that my `var filename` value is created when the page is first loaded and not when I click on the form submit button. I need the `var filename` when the person submits the form, after they have selected a file to upload.

Comment: @Charles847, I think I understand.  It sounds like you have two conditions that have to be met in order for you to warn the user.  1.) There is already data uploaded on the server, and 2.) the user is trying to upload new data.  Correct?  The code I put in my answer is intended to help you test for condition 2.  I have updated the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @Bill_Doughty Please see my updated snippet. The problem that I am having is that my `var csvAttachment` us always coming back as `""`. `""` Makes sense before I have selected a file to upload, but not after.

Comment: @Charles847, that's because you are assigning `csvAttachment` at page load, when the element value will always be empty.  You need to test inside your `destructionWarning` function as I show in my answer, so the state of the input element is current when you are checking it.